# Form response blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have some google script that generates an initial form then gathers a number does a lookup and then is supposed to return a second form (getfamily function). The second form which is dynamically generated returns blank. I can see the formHTML variable with data in the logger, but it comes up blank in the browser. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
var ssID="xxx";

var rows = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("studentinfo").getDataRange().getValues();

function doGet() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index2').evaluate()
    .setTitle('Lookup').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);   
    return html; 
};

function getfamily(form){
    Logger.log(form.familyid);
    var ssID="xxxx";
    var rows = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("studentinfo").getDataRange().getValues();
    var formHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    formHTML +="Hello!";
    formHTML += '<form id="students">';

    var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row){
        var message="made it";
        if (row[0] === form.familyid) {
            Logger.log(row[2]);
            formHTML+= '<input type="checkbox" name ="students value='+ row[1] + '">'+ row[2] + '<br>';
            return row[2];
        }
    });

    formHTML+='<input type="submit" value="CheckIn">';
    formHTML+='</form>';
    Logger.log(formHTML);
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(formHTML).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    return output;
};
```

Comment: Can you share the full script? This is hard to follow. Also the input attribute name isn't ever closed and value isn't ever opened. You might want to consider using a <label> tag too.

Comment: please also share the ```index2.html``` code

Answer (score 0):

Your input type="checkbox" line is hard to figure out what you want.  I presume that you plan in insert this form into an already exist DOM so no need the worrying about other tags just stick it in whatever div you have prepared for it.

```
function getfamily(form){
  var ssID="xxxx";
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("studentinfo").getDataRange().getValues();
  var formHTML='<form id="students">';
  var message="made it";
  rows.forEach(function(row){
    if (row[0]==form.familyid) {
      formHTTML=Utilities.formatString('<input type="checkbox" name="students" value="%s" /><br />',row[2]);//I presume that you want to change the name but I cant tell how you planned to do it.
    }
  });
  formHTML+='<input type="button" value="CheckIn" onClick="proceesForm(this.parentNode);" />';
  formHTML+='</form>';
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(formHTML);
};
```

You can use submit if you really must but I find using google.script.run to be a lot easier. We need to see more of what you're doing to provide a complete answer.